# How does the while loop work?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sap-iq

```
declare @t INT = 1 
declare @i INT = 1 

    while @t <= 5
BEGIN 
    while @i <= 40 
BEGIN 
    set @i = @i + 1
END

    set @t = @t + 1
    select @t
END
```

The result I get is `@t=2`. If I replace it with `@i` I get `@i=41`. Why does the `@variable` in the first while loop show 2, does it brake? Should it not show`@t=6`?

If I put the select `@t` at the end it will show 6, but what if you need every result from the iteration, you would not get the others results if you put the `@t` after the end, you would only get the last result. I would like the results 1,2,3,4,5,6 all go through `@t` ,and the end result should show only 6.

This is simplified example of a procedure that i have written, for every @t iteration the @i makes a full iteration, and then @t should go for the second iteration. @i works as planned, but the @t breaks after the first itteration.

(if @t = 1 , @i gets 40 rows from column 1 from some table, @t = 2 it gets 40 rows from column 2 from some table..ect) and writes it in @sql string, when she gets to 40 while loop breaks and goes into the @t loop, the @t should execute the @sql string(example it creates a view, so at the end i should have 6 views, but after the first execute the @t loop breaks.)

Comment: Whats the purpose of putting the second loop in the first one when it would run only once?

Comment: For every @t iteration, the @i makes everytime a full iteration and after it is done the @t should go the next iteration round.

Comment: Yes but one the 1st loop `i` would already add up to 40, so what's its impact during the second loop?

Comment: You don't reset @i anywhere, so it will be iterated only once. I assume you want something like `BEGIN set @i=1 while @i<=40 BEGIN set @i=@i+1`

Comment: Maybe you would prefer to use PRINT @t instead of select.

Comment: If you're running this from a stored procedure, you're returning the result with 'select @t' that's why the loop breaks in that sentence. That sentence should be below the last END.

Comment: i have edited my summary, it should give you a better explanation. pls dont be mad, im new to this. i believe it should be more understandable now.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your result in a table variable.

```
DECLARE @t INT = 1 
DECLARE @i INT = 1 

DECLARE @Result table(Id int)

while @t <= 5
BEGIN 
  while @i <= 40 
  BEGIN 
    set @i = @i + 1
  END

  INSERT INTO @Result(Id) values(@t)
  set @t = @t + 1

END
select Id FROM @Result
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you should have:

```
DECLARE @t INT = 1 
DECLARE @i INT = 1 

while @t <= 5
BEGIN 
  while @i <= 40 
  BEGIN 
    set @i = @i + 1
  END

  set @t = @t + 1
  --select @t   <-- this is breaking the loop before it ends
END
select @t
```

Comment: I know that m8 :) ,thats my problem, do you have any idea how to write that code so that all of the results go trough @t and not just the end result. I have edited my summary, read the end ,so you will understand it better.

Comment: If you can do it with @print it is a good start, or maybe also the answer to my problems ;)

Comment: Why don't you insert the value into a temporary table? Then select the temp table after the loop has ended